# Optimizing canvas drawing on Android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-canvas

I'm not sure why my code is (slightly) laggy, and doesn't run reliably at the same speed- I think I must be doing something wrong, as many other games are completely smooth.
The pertinent code in my Renderer class is here:

```
public void drawPicString(Location location, String string,
        RenderParams params) {
    //canvas.save();
    float rawX = location.getX();
    float rawY = location.getY();
    Bitmap rawbit = myImageCache.get(string);
    //Bitmap rawbit = provider.getBitmap(string);
    float thisWidth = rawbit.getWidth();
    float thisHeight = rawbit.getHeight();
    if(params.shouldResize){
        thisWidth = params.resizex;
        thisHeight = params.resizey;
    }
    float leftx = rawX-(thisWidth/2);
    float topy = rawY-(thisHeight/2);
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.setTranslate(leftx, topy);
    if(params.shouldResize){
        float toScaleY = ((float)thisHeight)/rawbit.getHeight();
        float toScaleX = ((float)thisWidth)/rawbit.getWidth();
        matrix.preScale(toScaleX, toScaleY);
        }
    if(params.shouldRotate){
        matrix.preRotate((float)Math.toDegrees(params.myangle),(float)(thisWidth/2.0),(float)(thisHeight/2.0));
    }
    canvas.drawBitmap(rawbit, matrix, paint);
}
```

The only other information I can think of that's pertinent is that myImageCache is a cache of bitmaps so that it doesn't have to fetch them from resources every time they're drawn. "canvas" is a canvas drawing on a surfaceview that's passed to it each frame before the drawing begins.

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Comment: Are params.shouldResize or params.shouldRotate true?  If so, you might want to cache the matrix unless it needs to be recalculated because of a change.

Comment: It depends on each draw.. The rotation is different every frame though, so I thought caching the matrix would just fill the memory up (plus the translation is different for each object each frame).

Comment: Note that most games use OpenGL for drawing which is a lot faster than canvas drawing. Also like DigitalGhost says, re-use a declared matrix as creating a new one every frame will trigger GC which causes lags.

Comment: I would try taking the matrix part out of it and seeing if that is the performance bottleneck.  I'm guessing the matrix operation on the entire image is what's causing the slowdown